# The case for using numerical high precision in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, precision

As part of developing a library of numerical methods, I routinely add unit tests. Most of the Assert.AreEqual type tests currently check at most 6 places of decimal, since precision beyond that is not required for this type of libraries. The tests have worked great so far in serving their purpose.

Recently, while working on a 64-bit version of the same library, I found that the results of quite a few unit tests are same through 6 places of decimal, but changes at 10th decimal place or beyond. How I found out about this happening in the first place is a completely different story, but chasing a few of those resulted in resolving few subtle bugs which I would have never knew existed.

Which brings me to the question: there seems to be a value in having unit tests check numbers at high precision (e.g., 10-12 places of decimal), or may be full precision (not even sure how to do that), even though the precision requirement of the library is not that high. What does the community here typically do for unit testing numerical values from scientific/numerical code? Any recommendations/suggestions/pointers?

More information: the library deals with double values. It is not meant to be a financial library etc., so I do not use decimal.

Comment: If the requirement is that the function return an answer correct to N decimal places, and your function passes for a set of carefully-chosen tests, it shouldn't matter whether your function is randomizing everything after the (N+1)th decimal place, or setting it equal to the system time divided by an unitialized pointer. I guess the real answer to your question, then, isn't "use greater precision", it's "use better test cases".

Comment: In JUnit, you can specify the degree of equality needed for floating point comparisons.

Comment: What datatype are you using?  Something you created for the library, `Decimal`, or `Float`/`Double`?  Cause I have 'bad' news for you if it's one of those last two...

Comment: @X-Zero: Updated with more information.

Comment: @Patrick87: I understand your point: I guess it can possibly be said that the unit test coverage was lacking since we found out those issues. Still, I am interested in knowing what is the group wisdom here .. what do people generally do?

Comment: @Samik R First off, testing cannot prove the absence of defects, only their presence. Given that, look at where your tests have failed to find defects in the past. Figure out why your tests failed, and what kind of tests could have caught the problem. Use that knowledge to develop better tests in the future. Note, though, that a "bug" that only ever causes digits after the Nth to be wrong isn't a defect if you only want N significant digits; don't waste time fixing a digital clock that can't display numbers higher than 60.

Comment: Since I don't have the exact answer to this problem I'm only recomending [Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/). There are examples how to handle this case and also some cheat sheets for different languages (btw please add language tag to your question).

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there exists any solution for your problem (without using quantum computers). there are two possibilities i heard of.

1. you are working with numbers that have finite representation (rational and all that is based on them). in this case you can simply compare/test those representations with full precision
2. representation is not finite (irrational and all that is based on them). in this case you simply can't do any operation (including testing) with full precision because you have finite amount of memory. you have to chose precision for your operation and then you can test only up to that precision.

there is also something 'between':

- you are using algebraic/symbolic calculation rather than value calculation. in this case even though you are working with (let's say) real number, in fact you are using its finite representation like 'pi', 'e' or 'sqrt(3)'. and that brings you to the #1
- you do operations like calculating sqrt(4), where your input and output are from #1 however your calculation process leads through #2 and therefore has all its limitations